# Can't use dictionaries in ansible

Tags: dictionary, yaml, ansible

I try to use dictionaries in ansible.

My `tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: Create Repository Folders
  file: path=/srv/svn/{{ ansible_fqdn }}/{{ item.value.reponame }} state=directory mode=0755 owner=apache group=apache
  with_dict:
    - repos
```

And my `vars/main.yml`:

```
---
repos:
  repo1:
    reponame: repository1
    repogroup: group1
  repo2:
    reponame: repository2
    repogroup: group2
  repo3:
    reponame: repository3
    repogroup: group3
```

But when running ansible-playbook I get following error:

```
TASK [svn : Create Repository Folders] *****************************************
fatal: [sun.beach.lan]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}
```

I followed the instructions on "Looping over Hashes" here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html

I guess I don't have the right YAML-syntax, but I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `-` infront of `repos` after `with_dict`

```
- name: Create Repository Folders
  file: path=/srv/svn/{{ ansible_fqdn }}/{{ item.value.reponame }} state=directory mode=0755 owner=apache group=apache
  with_dict:
    repos
```

If you are using ansible 2.0+ then use it like this:

```
with_dict: "{{ repos }}"
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks ... Can you explain why ansible 2.0+ works this way?

Comment: Using bare variables is deprecated in ansible 2.0+